# How to change the default 3 instances showing in a InlineModelAdmin object in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When you define a `InlineModelAdmin` class in *Django*, by default it shows 3 models in the admin page of the model that has a Foreign Key to the model I defined in the class.

**How can I change that?**

I just don't want to use `max_num` field, because when using it, I won't be able to add another instances in the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `max_num` use `extra`: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra